# Problem with a spacer

Tags: linux, bash, notifications, notify-send

I'm trying to send a notification through a notify-send

```
notify-send 'System' 'Dist files is already' $(du -h /var/cache/distfiles/ | tr -d '/var/cache/distfiles/')
```

But the spacer that I need cannot be displayed for some unknown to me reason, it outputs:

```
Invalid number of options.
```

But If I'll remove the spacer in there like this:

```
notify-send 'System' 'Dist files is already'$(du -h /var/cache/distfiles/ | tr -d '/var/cache/distfiles/')
```

It would works perfectly. Please, explain to me why is that so, I'm too dumb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command `tr` doesn't work as you intended:

```
-d, --delete
  delete characters in SET1, do not translate
```

Meaning that `tr` removes *single* characters from the SET1, for example:

```bsh
$ echo foobar | tr -d fb
ooar
```

---

Now let's see `man notify-send`:

```
SYNOPSIS
       notify-send [OPTIONS] {summary} [body]
```

So you have to pass **2** arguments (besides the OPTIONS). For example:

```bsh
$ notify-send 'System' 'foo' 'bar'
Invalid number of options.

$ notify-send 'System' 'foo'
<notification appears>
```

---

Let's see the output of `du -h /boot 2>/dev/null`:

```
4,0K    /boot/efi
3,4M    /boot/grub/x86_64-efi
2,3M    /boot/grub/fonts
8,0M    /boot/grub
146M    /boot
```

You have there *2* strings for each *row*! so your command results in (using `/boot` as example dir):

```bsh
notify-send 'System' 'Dist files is already' 4,0K   /boot
```

if the output is only 1 line, but as you can see, it could be many lines. So, a bunch of arguments.

---

When you remove the space, the resulting string is read as one, hence it looks like the correct 2 arguments.

---

So change your command to:

```bsh
notify-send 'System' "Dist files is already $(du -h /var/cache/distfiles/)"
```

only if you are sure that output is just one line. Here an example with `/root` folder

```bsh
$ notify-send 'System' "Dist files is already $(du -h /root 2> /dev/null)"
```

[image]

or

```bsh
$ notify-send 'System' "Dist files is already $(du -h /root | awk '{ print $1 }')"
```

[image]